# How do I update a parameter in css?

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, styles

I have a JSP which creates a CSS style file. In that JSP I am using a deviceWidth parameter which I get from a request being sent by the index page that is calling that JSP. I am also using a media query to catch an orientation change in the device.

The problem is, that once an orientation change has been made - I need to update the deviceWidth parameter, and that I don't know how to do.

I can't seem to be using a 'script' tag inside the 'style' block, and recalling the page by   window.location.href... with the new parameter value does not work either.

to clarify: this is how my JSP looks like:

```
<% 
  double deviceWidth = new Double(request.getParameter("width"));
%>

<style>
   .class1{
      BLA BLA BLA <%=deviceWidth%>px;
   }

   .class2{
      BLA BLA BLA <%=deviceWidth%>px;
   } 

   .class3{
      BLA BLA BLA <%=deviceWidth%>px;
   }

   @media only screen  and (orientation: portrait){
      .class1{
         FOO FOO <%=deviceWidth%>px;
      }

      .class2{
         FOO FOO <%=deviceWidth%>px;
      }

   }
</style>
```

only with MANY more class on each section, and the deviceWidth inside the media query should be a different one then the deviceWidth outside of the media query.
Any way i could just update it once and not individually for each element?

Answer (score 1):

just make two css classes:

```
.width1 {
 width: 300px;
}

.width2 {
 width: 500px;
}
```

then change the css class of your element with javascript (removeClass / addClass)

Comment: I think i might have been misunderstood... it's not about a css CLASS but a css whole FILE, containing many classes.
I am using a parameter deviceWidth in that css. for example:

.myDiv {left: <%=deviceWidth%> / 2}

When the user flips the device, the deviceWidth changes...

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a window resize event, grab the new window width and update the css accordingly:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var value = $(window).width();
    $('.myClass').css('width', value + 'px');
});
```

You may have to do some math with the window width value, but hopefully this gets you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you very much, first of all.
But if i get it right - i need to do that with each element i have in my page. is'nt there a way in which i can re-call the whole css only with a new deviceWidth value?

Comment: Oh, I thought you had multiple style sheets you wanted to use. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks alot Blake. I am sorry for nagging, but as far as i see it - it still forcing me to do that to every single element in my css, right? I will try to edit my question just to clarify